# Как сделать меню в виде выезжающего окна

Tags: android, java

В некоторых приложениях меню сделано в виде выезжающего окна с левой стороны.
Например приложения: "Сбербанк онлайн" или "В контакте".
Как это сделано?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)